# Not able to set date for native date field on android

Tags: android, ruby, automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to set a date on a native android application using with Ruby + Appium + UIAutomator2.

First, Appium desktop doesn't show native datepicker on the inspection field. So, I couldn't try to swipe for the datepicker wheels.
After that I tried

```
send_keys()
```

but not a chance.

Finally, I tried the command below with "appium --relaxed-security":

`driver.execute_script('mobile: shell', {'command': 'input text', 'args': '04 / 05 / 1990'})`
but it didn't work neiether.

How to solve the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using UI Automator Viewer (which is part of Android SDK)?
You can connect a real device or use emulator, start the app, start UI Automator Viewer and grab a screenshot with it. You will be able to see entire screen and inspect it. This will help with creating the selectors for those nasty native elements.

Video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBhfYAYKZF4).